# How to format java code automatically to add braces

Tags: java, eclipse

How to format java code automatically to add braces in eclispe

```
if (type == null) {
    if (other.type != null)
        return false;
} else if (!type.equals(other.type))
    return false;
```

Comment: Well if you're going to ask for Eclipse support the least you can do is specify what version you're using and what OS you're on.

Comment: Try `CRTL + SHIFT + F` if on windows , if on Mac then try `⌘ + ⇧ + F`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *insert* braces *automatically* you have to update the java editor in your preferences,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify your OS , But generally following key combinations works to format code in eclipse :

Windows Os : <kbd>CRTL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Mac Os :<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Hope this will help you.